# Keeping history of buttons id using android

Tags: java, android, button

I am learning android programming so be cool with me.
My question is, i am having for example 5 buttons.User clicks any one button out of 5 and clicks another button.So how to keep track of previously clicked button ids.So the 2nd button clicks output is based on the previous button.

Can any one throw me pointers on that.I am new to java and android.

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend you to follow (Screen State) base approach; as below:

1.) Create Screen State class and assign each state a unique value.

2.) You should mention Screen state stack and the current screen state.

3.) when you press a button, call a OnstateChange() function. Which should determine the next screen (based on current screen and whether user moved forward or backward). If user moved backward, pop the screen from stack and mark it as current screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remember only the very last button you clicked, use a class member variable to remember something about it (the button's ID, or a numeric index, or something). You should set this member variable in the onClick() call corresponding to the button.

If you need to remember the entire history of clicked buttons, use a List implementation (ArrayList should be fine) and add() the information about the button (the button's ID, or a numeric index, or something) in the onClick() method corresponding to the button.

If you have different OnClickHandler's for each button, this is pretty straightforward. If you share an OnClickHandler, you will need to use some identifying property of the View you get passed in as an argument to onClick().